# SUM cells in Excel BY their font color

Tags: excel, vba, fonts

I have a range of cells in Excel that need to be summed by their font color. 
Column A is just names of vendors and it's obviously the entire month of May:
[image: img]

Ideally, I'd like to know the sum of black, red or blue cells for this range
So I developed two scenarios, one with and without macros.

1. **without VBA**

Add a string to red and black cells to know that they are "different"
E.G. change 268 to 268c and 66.5 to 66.5u but leave 52.96 unchanged

And use the array formula below:

```
{=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(B7:C16),B7:C16,NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(B7:C16,3))))}
```

This skips the .5 in 66.5 but works, and as soon as I change the 3 in the `LEFT` function (which truncates the cell from text to string) to `LEN(B6:C17)-1` it doesn't work.

2. **with VBA**

Insert module and create this formula, which works on its own:

```
Function GetCellColor(ByVal Target As Range) As Integer
    GetCellColor = Target.Font.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Using the formula below (gives error if it's array formula or not):

```
=SUM(IF(getcellcolor(B7:C16)=3,B7:C16,0))
```

*I could write code which goes through each cell manually and adds, but I am wondering what the problem with each scenario is...

Comment: Seems to me like you're working backwards.  Formatting conditionally and then trying to figure out which ones were formatted?  If you take a step back you could do everything in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As QHarr points out you can't use `Font.ColorIndex` on a multi-cell range.

Here's a version of your UDF which works in your original worksheet function:

```
Function GetCellColor(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim arr(), r As Long, c As Long
    ReDim arr(1 To Target.Rows.Count, 1 To Target.Columns.Count)
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            arr(r, c) = Target(r, c).Font.ColorIndex
        Next
    Next
    GetCellColor = arr
End Function
```

Comment: QHarr gave you a good answer - I think that deserves the "accepted" flag you orginally awarded.  Or you can flag >1 answer I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `Target.Font.ColorIndex` on a range of more than one cell. Using a larger range will yield `null`.

You could pass a range in and loop summing in the UDF. Also, pass the colour as an argument to the function.

**Single colour:**

```
Public Function GetCellColor(ByRef Target As Range, ByVal targetColour As Long) As Long
    Dim outValue As Long, currentcell As Range
    For Each currentcell In Target.Cells
        If currentcell.Font.ColorIndex = targetColour Then outValue = outValue + currentCell
    Next currentcell
    GetCellColor = outValue
End Function
```

---

**Up to 3 colours:**

This probably needs improving but if using up to 3 colours, with the last 2 being optional, and where individual colours should not be passed more than once, you could try something like:

```
Public Function GetCellColor(ByRef Target As Range, ByVal targetColour As Long, Optional ByVal targetColour2 As Variant, Optional ByVal targetColour3 As Variant) As Long
    Dim outValue As Long, currentcell As Range

    Select Case True
    Case Not IsMissing(targetColour2) And Not IsMissing(targetColour3)
        If targetColour2 = targetColour3 Or targetColour = targetColour2 Or targetColour = targetColour3 Then GoTo earlyExit
    Case IsMissing(targetColour2) And Not IsMissing(targetColour3)
        If targetColour = targetColour3 Then GoTo earlyExit
    Case Not IsMissing(targetColour2) And IsMissing(targetColour3)
        If targetColour = targetColour2 Then GoTo earlyExit
    End Select

    For Each currentcell In Target.Cells
        If currentcell.Font.ColorIndex = targetColour Then outValue = outValue + currentcell
        If Not IsMissing(targetColour2) Then
            If currentcell.Font.ColorIndex = targetColour2 Then
                outValue = outValue + currentcell
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsMissing(targetColour3) Then
            If currentcell.Font.ColorIndex = targetColour3 Then
                outValue = outValue + currentcell
            End If
        End If
    Next currentcell
    GetCellColor = outValue

    Exit Function
earlyExit:
  GetCellColor = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Comment: I have added up to 3 colours being accepted as arguments in version 2.